# JQuery animate an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched and I couldn't find anything like my problem, so I am sorry if this is already asked.
I have an input field and a button. If the text entered matched "IA" the borders of the input field should turn red, green, blue and white. Mine are only going to red and stopping. 
Here is the code. I will appreciate any help.
HTML:

```
       <body>
                <input id="enter" type="text"> 
                <button id="validate">Validate</button>
          </body>
```

JQuery:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#validate").click(function(){
                var a = "ia";
                if($("#enter").val()==a){
                    $("#enter").animate({
                        border: "3px solid red"
                    },1000, function(){
                        border: "3px solid green"
                    },1000, function(){
                        border: "3px solid blue"
                    },1000, function(){
                        border: "3px solid white"
                    },1000);
                }

            });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with:

```
$("#enter").animate({
    border: "3px solid red"
},1000).animate({
    border: "3px solid green"
},1000).animate({
    border: "3px solid blue"
},1000).animate({
    border: "3px solid white"
},1000);
```